# HTML - vertical align at middle

Tags: html, css, text, alignment

Im trying to make a navigation bar for my website. I want to change the heigth of the bar with its elements.

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  height: 100px;
}

li {
  float: left;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}

li form input {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="#menu">Menu</a></li>
  <li>
    <form>
      <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search..">
    </form>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I tried to align my elements vertically at the middle with the 'align-vertical' tag. It doesn't work.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to use `padding` instead of `height` on the `ul`.

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 50px 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

li {
  float: left;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}

li form input {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="#menu">Menu</a></li>
  <li>
    <form>
      <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search..">
    </form>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Another way it to use flex.

```
ul {
...
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

li {
  float: left;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}

li form input {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="#menu">Menu</a></li>
  <li>
    <form>
      <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search..">
    </form>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It works! I have to wait 10 minutes until I can accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

One of the easiest ways to center elements vertically is to use Flexbox. Adding:

`display: flex;
align-items: center;`

to the styles on your UL will center the li's vertically.

Answer (score 0):

`vertical-align` property only works with `display: inline-block`. You can take advantage of `flex` which has now wide support.

What I did - 
Added `display: flex` on container that is `ul` in this case. Also, added `align-contents` to make it in the middle of the navbar.

Further reading - 
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```js
ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: #333;
        height: 100px;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
    }

   

    li a {
        display: block;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align:middle;
        text-decoration: none;

    }

    li a:hover {
        background-color: #111;
    }

    li form input{
        vertical-align:middle;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul>
          <li><a class="active" href="#menu">Menu</a></li>
          <li>
              <form>
                <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search..">
              </form>
          </li>
        </ul>

    </body>
</html>
```